# ¿Cómo solucionar error al intentar añadir una url de imgur con formato de imagen?

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy programando un bot de discord que con un comando puedas borrar la imagen de imgur a traves de otro comando que te proporciona el hash para poder borrar x imagen subida a imgur, pero tengo un problema que al intentar poner una url en formato .png Ejemplo:

```
https://i.imgur.com/6Z9FfZy.png
```

si lo añaden de esa forma me tira un error en consola y es este:

[image]

Enteoria deberian de añadir el hash para poder borrar x imagen pero me gustaria que si añadieran una imagen en formato .png jpg diera que muestre error en discord

Este es mi código que estoy usando actualmente:

```
@slash.slash(
    name="borrar", description="Escribe La id para borrar la iamgen",
    options=[
                create_option(
                  name="borrar_imagen",
                  description="Escribe el ID para borrar la imagen",
                  option_type=3,
                  required=True
                ),
                 
    ])
                  
            
             

    


async def borrar(ctx:SlashContext, borrar_imagen:str):
    url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{borrar_imagen}"
    payload={}
    files={}
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " +  config["token_imgur"]}
    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Imagen borrada con exito!", color=0x00ff11)
    if response.json()["status"] == 200:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="No está permitido paginas webs", color=0xff0019)        
    if response.json()["status"] == 400:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)  

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Error!", color=0xff0019)   
    if response.json()["status"] == 403:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
```

No se cómo solucionar este problema, alguien me podria echar una mano?, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi lo puedes solucionar:

```
async def borrar(ctx:SlashContext, borrar_imagen:str):
    url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{borrar_imagen}"
    payload={}
    files={}
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " +  config["token_imgur"]}
    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Imagen borrada con exito!", color=0x00ff11)
    if response.status_code ==200:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="No está permitido paginas webs", color=0xff0019)        
    if response.status_code ==400:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)  

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Error!", color=0xff0019)   
    if response.status_code ==403:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True) 



    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="formato imagen no está permitido", color=0xff0019)   
    if response.status_code ==405:
         await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
```